# private method `update_without_password' called for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, cancancan

I am following [this tutorial](http://hibbard.eu/authentication-with-devise-and-cancancan-in-rails-4-2/) on cancancan authentication, and specifically wanting admins to update users without needing a password. I've also seen [this](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable:update_without_password) suggestion, but am unsure how to adapt it into my own code. When I click update, it says 'NoMethodError in UsersController#update' private method `update_without_password' called for nil:NilClass

My app returns all the user's params, so I don't understand what's happening here. Still very new to rails - let me know if you need any further information. Thank you in advance!

USERS CONTROLLER

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!



 def update
  if user_params[:password].blank?
    user_params.delete(:password)
    user_params.delete(:password_confirmation)
  end


  successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, user_params)
                           @user.update(user_params)
                         else
                           @user.update_without_password(user_params)
                         end
 respond_to do |format|
    if successfully_updated
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end


  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    respond_to_not_found(:js, :xml, :html)
  end


private
def needs_password?(user, params)
  params[:password].present?
end

def update_without_password(user_params)
  user.update_without_password(user_params)
end



def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name, :role_id, :accepted)
end
```

EDIT FORM

```
<h3><%= @user == @current_user ? "Your Account Settings" : "Edit User" %></h3>

<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
 <p><%= f.label :first_name %></p>
 <p><%= f.text_field :first_name %></p>

 <p><%= f.label :last_name %></p>
 <p><%= f.text_field :last_name %></p>

 <p><%= f.label :email %></p>
 <p><%= f.text_field :email %></p>
  <% if can? :read, Role %>
 <%= collection_select(:user, :role_id, Role.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true}) %>
  <% end %>
 <p><%= f.submit "Update" %></p>
<% end %>
```

What am I missing here? Please let me know if should provide anything else. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you're seeing that error because `@user` is not being instantiated in the `update` method. You need to set `@user` to an instance of your `User` model. Without seeing your full app, I can't know for sure, but you should have access to `:id` in the params hash, allowing you to set up `@user` doing something like this:

`@user = User.find(params[:id])`

Since you're digging into CanCan, I'd highly encourage you to read through [their documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for the `load_and_authorize_resource` method. You use it in your controllers to D.R.Y. up repetitive code that loads the object or collection you want to work with. It uses the name of the controller you're in and the `:id` value from `params` to automatically instantiate your resource. So, in your `show`, `edit`, and `update` methods, it would instantiate the singular `@user` object in your `UsersController`, and in your `index` method, it would instantiate the collection `@users`.

FWIW, you might wonder why you aren't seeing the `NoMethodError` crop up on the `if needs_password?(@user, user_params)` line. Even though `@user` is used there, if you look at the definition of your `needs_password?` method, it takes a `user` argument, but doesn't actually use it, so it won't complain about the fact that `@user` is nil when it's called. However, in this line `@user.update_without_password(user_params)`, you're directly sending the `update_without_password` method/message to the `@user` variable, which is `nil`.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Wow this is so simple, yet I kept overlooking that every time. Thank you sooo much for looking through - all I had to do was add exactly what you asked - @user = User.find(params[:id]) and it works perfectly.